# Why are objects in the simplicial category cosimplicial?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

From [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+object),

> A cosimplicial object in C is similarly a functor out of the opposite category, Δ→C.

Δ here means the simplicial category.

That implies that the the identity functor on the simplicial category is a cosimplicial object in the simplicial category. That sounds really strange. Why is that?

Comment: It is, why should that be "strange" ?

Comment: It seems just obvious that simplicial objects should be related by arrows in the same way as objects in the simplicial category, rather than the objects in the cosimplicial category.

Comment: Are we discussing naming and notation issues or is there something that you don't understand, and if so what is it ?

Comment: A cosimplicial object in a category $C$ is a functor $\Delta \rightarrow C$, so the identity functor $\Delta \rightarrow \Delta$ is a cosimplicial object in $\Delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning some more, I understand why simplicial objects are defined that way.

To understand it, consider a triangle, a 2-simplex. Concretely, let's regard it as a subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Write it as $S_{123}$.

Then consider its sub-simplices. It has three edges (1-simplex) $S_{12}, S_{13}, S_{23}$, and three vertices (0-simplex) $S_1, S_2, S_3$.

Now, collect these pieces into three sets $\Delta(2), \Delta(1), \Delta(0)$, defined by
$$\Delta(2) = \{S_{123}\}$$
$$\Delta(1) = \{S_{12}, S_{13}, S_{23}\}$$
$$\Delta(0) = \{S_1, S_2, S_3\}$$

Now, we can define three "face maps" of type $\Delta(2) \to \Delta(1)$, each sending $S_{123}$ to a different face of it. Similarly, we can define two "face maps" of type $\Delta(1) \to \Delta(0)$, each sending $S_{ij}$ to a different vertex of it.

Now, we can already see how, from considering a simplex and its subsimplices, we are approaching something like the simplex category $\Delta$. So we would guess that a general simplex can be modelled by a functor $\Delta \to Set$.

However, notice that in $\Delta$, there are two arrows of type $[0] \to [1]$, but here, we constructed two arrows of type $\Delta(1) \to \Delta(0)$, so we get our clue that we should use functors out of $\Delta^{op}$ instead.

Finally, note that we have made only face maps, and still need degeneracy maps. What's a degenerate 1-simplex? That is, what's a degenerate edge? It is a vertex pretending to be an edge. There are three such edges: $S_{11}, S_{22}, S_{33}$. Add them to $\Delta(1)$.

There is only one way to construct a degenerate 1-simplex from a 0-simplex: $S_i \mapsto S_{ii}$, consequently there is only one degenerate map $\Delta(0) \to \Delta(1)$. This correspond to the one degenerate map $[1] \to [0]$ in $\Delta$.

Similarly, there are four ways to construct a degenerate 2-simplex from a 1-simplex: $S_{ij} \mapsto S_{iii}, S_{iij}, S_{ijj}, S_{jjj}$. These correspond to the four degenerate maps $[1] \to [0]$ in $\Delta$.

Now, in general, we can construct [simplicial complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) using the same procedure. The result is a sequence of $\Delta(0), \Delta(1), \Delta(2)...$, each containing the 0-simplices, 1-simplices, 2-simplicies... of this simplicial complex. There would be face maps and degeneracy maps between these $\Delta(n)$, satisfying the [simplicial identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+identities).

In short, we obtain a functor $F: \Delta^{op} \to Set$. This map sends $[n]$ to $\Delta(n)$, and $f: [n] \to [m]$ to $F(f): \Delta(m) \to \Delta(n)$ defined by $F(f)(S_{v_1 v_2 ... v_m}) = S_{v_{f(1)} v_{f(2)} ... v_{f(n)}}$. Here, $S_{v_1 v_2 ... v_m}$ should be thought of as a simplex with vertices $v_1, v_2 ... v_m$.

That's why a contravariant functors out of $\Delta$ deserves the name "simplicial sets".

Answer (score 0):

A simplicial object is named after a (semi)simplicial complex, which is a contravariant functor from $\Delta$, not after the simplicial category $\Delta$.